# When an object of a class has arguments, how do you pass it as an argument of a method in another class

Tags: python, oop

This new class(CashRegister) should accept retail object as an argument
how do I go about it
the class in retail has 3 argument too

```
import retail
item = retail.RetailItem(desc, unit, price)

class CashRegister:

    def purchase_item(self):
        pass

    def get_total(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are referring to inheritance, if is that in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp you can find some examples of inheritance, hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).